# Docker runs but can't connect

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to run a docker for pihole.  And I was able to get it up and running successfully.   The one thing I don't understand is when I try to add an extra volume I can't connect to its web interface even though it appears to be running.

I run it with:

```
sudo docker run -d \
   --name pihole   \
   --net=host      \
   -p 53:53/tcp    \
   -p 53:53/udp    \
   -p 80:80        \
   --volume=/dcfg/pihole:/etc/pihole       \
   --volume=/dcfg/dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d \
   -e TZ="America/Toronto"                 \
   -e WEBPASSWORD="PASSWORD"               \
   -e ServerIP="SERVERIP"                  \
   --restart=unless-stopped                \
   diginc/pi-hole:latest
```

when I add:

```
--volume=/dcfg/pihole_log:/var/log
```

OR:

```
--volume=/dcfg/pihole_lighttpd:/etc/lighttpd
```

then it doesn't produce any errors, I just can't connect to the web interface.  When I stop the docker, remove the extra volume and run it again, everything works again.   I also tried experimenting with another project's docker and had the same results.   So there is something I am missing.  Perhaps only allowed 2 volumes?

Comment: just use -v with -v /dcfg/pihole and run -it instead of -d to debug it

Comment: get the [logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) it would be easy to rectify the problem.

Comment: you were correct, removing the -d was enough to get going.   thanks Adiii!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove -d from the above would allow for more -v options to be used.